# CoordinatorLayout and RecyclerView issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using CoordinatorLayout and NestedScrollView for creating an activity looks like this:
[image]

My layout structure is like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout          
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MovieDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgToolbarImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/backdrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    ... >
                    <ImageView
                       ... />
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <TextView
                        ... />

                <TextView
                        ... />

                <ImageView
                        ... />

                <TextView
                    ... />

                <com.aminiam.moviekade.custom_view.ExpandableTextView
                    ... />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                   ... />

                <com.aminiam.moviekade.custom_view.DotIndicator
                    ... />

                <View
                    ... />

                <LinearLayout
                     ... >

                    <TextView
                        ... />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        ... />
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    ... />

                <TextView
                    ... />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_off" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I add RecyclerView to the layout, NestedScrollView will goes under the AppBarLayout, like image below:

[image]

I tested some ways for fixing this issue like put NestedScrollView into a FrameLayout or add `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` and `android:fillViewport="true"` attributes to NestedScrollView but these couldn't fix the issue.

Comment: What is the height of `recyclerview`? `wrap_content`?

Comment: No I added a fix height for that. android:layout_height="150dp"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` into your `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" > 

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** `descendantFocusability` Defines the relationship between the ViewGroup and its descendants when looking for a View to take focus. *Here we are blocking that.*